# 404 deploy Angular, NGINX and Docker in container registry

Tags: docker, nginx

I have an application written in Angular 7 that I am deploying to a Docker container with NGINX. When I run the container, everything works perfectly except that if i Refresh the page in the browser (F5) I get an NGINX 404 error page.

Here is my nginx.conf file from which you can see ive tried "try_files"

> server {
> listen       80;
> server_name  localhost;
>
> ```
>     location / {
>         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
>         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
>         index  index.html index.htm;
>     }
>
>     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
>     location = /50x.html {
>         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

My dockerfile

> ```
> # Stage 1: Compile and Build angular codebase
>
> # Use official node image as the base image
> FROM node:latest as build
>
> # Set the working directory
> WORKDIR /app
>
> # Add the source code to app
> COPY . .
>
> # Install all the dependencies
> RUN npm install
>
> # Generate the build of the application
> RUN npm run build --prod
>
>
> # Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server
>
> # Use official nginx image as the base image
> FROM nginx:latest
>
> RUN ["rm", "-rf", "/usr/share/nginx/html"]
>
> COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
> COPY --from=build /app/dist/f22-front /usr/share/nginx/html
> ```